# Codeigniter RESTful API - How to get parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I have this model in my Codeigniter setup:

```
function get_all_artists(){

    $this->db->select('artist_id, artist_name');
    $this->db->from('artists');
    return $this->db->get();    
}
```

How do I fetch those parameters in my Rest_Controller setup? How would the `_get()`-function look like?

```
public function artists_get()  
{  
 ???
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to access the result returned by `get_all_artists()` function?

Comment: You mean just calling the function from your controller? $this->load->model('model_name'); '$artists = $this->model_name->get_all_artists();

Comment: yes, I need to send json to my frontend from the result

Comment: ok, got it....thanks for letting me know.  I wrote an answer but maybe it doesn't apply then.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function artists_get(){  
  $this->load->model('your_model_name');// load model here
  $res = $this->your_model_name->get_all_artists();
  $result = $res->result_array();// get result as associative array
  return json_encode($result);// encode with json
}
```

With this library you need to append the method type to the function name. `_get` for`GET`, `_post` for `POST`, `_put` for `PUT`, `_delete` for `DELETE`. e.g. `functionname_get()`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer you'll want to retrieve results as an array.  So `$this->db->get()->result_array();`
To retrieve data from the model:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');

$artists = $this->model_name->get_all_artists();
```

If you want to send json to front end then you need to do something like this:

```
$vars['artists'] = json_encode($artists);

$this->_getTemplate('default')->build('artists_page', $vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [REST EXTENSION for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) then you must create an object and invoke the method "Respose".

```
public function artists_get() {
  $response = array(
    'status'=>TRUE,
    'data'=>$result, // This can be an object or array
    'obs'=>'all',
  );
  $this->response($response);
}
```

That's the official way to do it... and it works perfectly!